# Problems Connecting to Minimized Signal

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, pygtk

**Problem:** I have a gtk.Dialog. Whenever the 'minimize' button on the dialog is clicked, the window is destroyed.

**Question:** How can I connect to the minimize button of a gtk.Dialog so that I can iconify the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it's the minimize button? Because GTK doesn't deal with (or even know about the existence of) minimize buttons at all, they are part of the window manager.